# EOF-Exception reading ServletInputStream

Tags: java, servlets

I have an easy Test-Object that I want to send to a servlet, but I got an EOF-error. If I ask if the ServletInputStream is ready I got a false. Can anyone help me please?

Test-class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Test implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}
```

Connection to the servlet:

```
   URLConnection yc = connect.openConnection();
        yc.setDoInput(true);
        yc.setDoOutput(true);
        
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        
        Test test = new Test();
        
  
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream 
          = new ObjectOutputStream(yc.getOutputStream());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(test);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
```

the servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
                ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
                
                try {
            
                    Test test = (Test) objectInputStream.readObject();
                    objectInputStream.close();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
}
```

```
Here is the exception trace on servlet:
Servlet.service() for servlet [TransactionServlet] in context with path [/HashingNode] threw exception
java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2860)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3355)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:939)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:381)
    at TransactionServlet.doPost(TransactionServlet.java:58)
    at TransactionServlet.doGet(TransactionServlet.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `yc`? Please show more context.

Comment: Please also include the full exception message and stack trace

Comment: yc is a  URLConnection Object: URL connect = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HashingNode/TransactionServlet?action=UNCONFIRMEDTRANSACTION");
 URLConnection yc = connect.openConnection();

Comment: @Kosmita please edit the question to include all of the details needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: Its added, hope, someone can find a solution.